# Deleting record from query table composed of other table's columns(?)

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on my A Level computing project and I'm really coming close to the deadline and panicking because I need to document before i can hand it in but this is holding me back big time!

I'm trying to delete a record from a table that is made of columns of other tables via a query, but I literally have no idea how! What I should be deleting, how I am supposed to let VB know which record to remove etc, it's essentially (Well, what I'm aiming for) is to delete a record that contains the ID of a Youth and the ID of a trip the Youth is assigned to, but both are primary keys from other tables, sorry if I'm not explaining this too well, I don't understand it very well myself, and when I click the remove button I've assigned, it doesn't do anything and just deletes the information in the comboboxes instead of removing the record i want

```
Private Sub btn_remove_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_remove.Click

    Clubconnection.Open()
    Dim sqlQuery3 As String = "SELECT * FROM tblYouths"
          Dim db_com As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, Clubconnection)
    db_com.ExecuteNonQuery()


    sqlQuery3 = "DELETE * FROM tblYouth_trips WHERE YouthID = cmb_youth_remove.selectedvalue.tostring AND TripID = cmb_trip_remove.selectedvalue.tostring"
    Clubconnection.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: there is no way we can tell is the SQL is correct without knowing the column names; the *way* you create your SQL is wrong: `WHERE YouthID = cmb_youth_remove.selectedvalue.tostring` is likely wrong because you probably do not have a column named, literally,  `cmb_youth_remove.selectedvalue.tostring`.  Use SQL Parameters.

Answer (score 0):

try this

change
sqlQuery3 = "DELETE * FROM tblYouth_trips WHERE YouthID = cmb_youth_remove.selectedvalue.tostring AND TripID = cmb_trip_remove.selectedvalue.tostring"

to

sqlQuery3 = "DELETE * FROM tblYouth_trips WHERE YouthID = '" & cmb_youth_remove.selectedvalue.tostring & "' AND TripID = '" & cmb_trip_remove.selectedvalue.tostring &"'"

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, it's not giving an error or even showing any sign of anything changing

Comment: you should debug your program after you click the remove button and point your mouse on cmb_youth_remove.selectedvalue.tostring and see what it contains